# Why can't I duck reverb in the mix bus?

Tags: audio, unity

i'm surprised there is so little documentation on this issue. But i'm trying to duck the audio on all the mix buses in Unity so that you can clearly hear the VO of the game.

Now it works great except that I have some reverb zones in the game and any sound that plays in these reverb zones, the actual reverb itself is NOT DUCKED.

So the VO is accompanied with a huge wall of wishy washy muddy noise.

Anyone deal with this before? How can we deal with this?

Comment: Should probably be moved to Game Development.

Comment: fascinating, I never noticed that problem, Selcuk.  Hopefully someone has an answer